Auto Populate WooCommerce Variable Product Related Options
I have a product in WooCommerce and Its Variable Product, with multiple options for the product, like:

Volume
Top-mm
Bottom-mm

I want, when I select the volume, then the rest of the option should be auto filed instead of selecting each of them.
Currently, When I select a volume, then the other related filed shows "Choose an option" but in the drop down the original value already available. So I want to show the original value instead "Choose an option"
Live Example: Product
JS I have tried but it did not worked:
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Define the mappings for volume to top and bottom diameters
    const volumeMappings = {
        '9-OZ': { top_mm: '80', bottom_mm: '115' },
        '12-OZ': { top_mm: '85', bottom_mm: '120' }
    };

    // Listen for change event on the volume dropdown
    $('#volume').on('change', function () {
        var selectedVolume = $(this).val(); // Get the selected volume value

        // Check if the selected volume has a mapping defined
        if (volumeMappings[selectedVolume]) {
            // Retrieve the corresponding top and bottom values
            var topValue = volumeMappings[selectedVolume].top_mm;
            var bottomValue = volumeMappings[selectedVolume].bottom_mm;

            // Update the top-mm dropdown to the corresponding value
            $('#top-mm').val(topValue);

            // Update the bottom-mm dropdown to the corresponding value
            $('#bottom-mm').val(bottomValue);
        } else {
            // If no mapping is found, reset the dropdowns
            $('#top-mm').val('');
            $('#bottom-mm').val('');
        }
    });
});


To auto select Top and Bottom values from the select Volume, try the following based on your product HTML structure (from the provided link):


jQuery(function ($) {
    const volumeSelector = 'table.variations #volume',
        volumeMappings = {
        '9 OZ': { top_mm: '80', bottom_mm: '115' },
        '12 OZ': { top_mm: '85', bottom_mm: '120' }
    };

    // Function that auto select Top and Bottom values
    function autoSelectTopBottom( volumeValue ) {
        var topValue = '', bottomValue = ''; // Initializing

        // Loop through the Volume Mappings (data)
        $.each( volumeMappings, function( index, values ) {
            // Check for the selected volume
            if ( volumeValue === index ) {
                topValue    = values.top_mm;
                bottomValue = values.bottom_mm;
            } 
        });
        // Set Top and Bottom values
        $('table.variations #top-mm').val(topValue);
        $('table.variations #bottom-mm').val(bottomValue);
    } 

    // On Start
    autoSelectTopBottom( $(volumeSelector).val() );

    // On Change
    $(document.body).on('change', volumeSelector, function () {
        autoSelectTopBottom( $(this).val() );
    });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><label for="volume">Volume</label></th>
            <td class="value">
                <select id="volume" class="" name="attribute_volume" data-attribute_name="attribute_volume" data-show_option_none="yes">
                    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                    <option value="9 OZ" class="attached enabled">9 OZ</option>
                    <option value="12 OZ" class="attached enabled">12 OZ</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><label for="top-mm">Top (mm)</label></th>
            <td class="value">
                <select id="top-mm" class="" name="attribute_top-mm" data-attribute_name="attribute_top-mm" data-show_option_none="yes">
                    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                    <option value="80" class="attached enabled">80</option>
                    <option value="85" class="attached enabled">85</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><label for="bottom-mm">Bottom (mm)</label></th>
            <td class="value">
                <select id="bottom-mm" class="" name="attribute_bottom-mm" data-attribute_name="attribute_bottom-mm" data-show_option_none="yes">
                    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                    <option value="115" class="attached enabled">115</option>
                    <option value="120" class="attached enabled">120</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>



Run the code snippet above, it works.
Be careful because the volume values from the select field were not the same as those defined in volumeMappings constant.
